# Removing overloaded method in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, comparator

There are 2 overloaded methods.
Each of these methods converts a list of one type to a list of a different type. But the first method uses a comparator.

```
class SomeClass {
    public static <T, G> List<G> toListOfNewType(List<T> inputList,
                                                 Function<T, G> mapperFunction, 
                                                 Comparator<? super G> comparator) {
           return Stream.ofNullable(inputList)
                        .flatMap(List::stream)
                        .map(mapperFunction)
                        .sorted(comparator)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    public static <T, G> List<G> toListOfNewType(List<T> inputList,
                                                 Function<T, G> mapperFunction) {
           return Stream.ofNullable(inputList)
                        .flatMap(List::stream)
                        .map(mapperFunction)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

As you can see, most of the lines are duplicated. How can I get rid of the second method so that passing null to the first as a comparator will not break it?

In other words, how to make the first work without a comparator?

Comment: Include a `null` check?

Answer (score 3):

Use an `if` statement to check for `null`:

```
public static <T, G> List<G> toListOfNewType(List<T> inputList,
                                             Function<T, G> mapperFunction,
                                             Comparator<? super G> comparator) {
    Stream<G> stream = Stream.ofNullable(inputList)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .map(mapperFunction);
    if (comparator != null)
        stream = stream.sorted(comparator);
    return stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static <T, G> List<G> toListOfNewType(List<T> inputList,
                                             Function<T, G> mapperFunction) {
    return toListOfNewType(inputList, mapperFunction, null);
}
```

Comment: probably make the second method `private` and document that `Comparator` could be null. Though this is misleading, at least for me. A `null` `Comparator` _can_ mean sort by natural order

Comment: @Eugene Why should the second method be `private`? Then no one would call it. --- As for documenting, that's entirely up to OP to decide whether that's needed.

Comment: actually why keep it at all? if you document the purpose of the third argument you don't need that method at all. And isn't `Stream::ofNullable` java-9?

Comment: @Eugene I kept the overload to show that you can keep it without having duplicate lines, which seems to be the main issue that OP had. I kept it because having overloads omitting optional parameters is common in java (see e.g. the stream APIs). I kept it so OP would know that the choice is available. OP can choose to keep it or not. --- And what does Java 9 have to do with anything? It's the code from the question. If you have a problem with OP using a Java 9 method while tagging `java-8`, you should leave a comment to OP on the question, don't blame the answer.

Comment: I believe its a matter of choice as to how the APIs are exposed to the clients. But with the current approach the design reads more like `public static <T, G> List<G> toListOfNewType(List<T> inputList,  Function<T, G> mapperFunction, @Nullable Comparator<? super G> comparator)`. On the other hand, the Comparator could have been `@NonNull` for the user and redirecting them for such cases to make use of the overloaded method. (Just an opinion.) ... I would second the thought that Java version doesn't really matter much here @Eugene.

Comment: Just a matter of readability and the level of permissible duplicate code, but I'd initially thought of something like `<T, G> List<G> toListOfNewType(List<T> inputList, Function<T, G> mapperFunction, Comparator<? super G> comparator){ Stream<G> stream = toListOfNewType(inputList, mapperFunction); return comparator == null ? stream.collect(Collectors.toList()) : stream.sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList()); }` alongwith `<T, G> Stream<G> toListOfNewType(List<T> inputList, Function<T, G> mapperFunction){ return Stream.ofNullable(inputList).flatMap(List::stream).map(mapperFunction);  }`

Comment: @Naman `toListOfNewType` would be a horrible name for the second one, since it doesn't return a list. --- Your suggestion is still duplicating the `collect(Collectors.toList())` call, while there is no duplicate logic in the code in this answer.

Comment: @Andreas `java-9` was indeed something for the OP, my bad for posting it in the comments under your question.

Answer (score 3):

While I second the goal of removing code duplication on the implementation side, I consider assigning a special meaning to `null` instead of clear overloaded methods a step into the wrong direction.

You can still have two methods for the caller's convenience with no code duplication in the implementation, e.g.:

```
public static <T, G> List<G> toListOfNewType(List<T> inputList,
                                             Function<T, G> mapperFunction,
                                             Comparator<? super G> comparator) {
  List<G> resultList = toListOfNewType(inputList, mapperFunction);
  if(!resultList.isEmpty()) resultList.sort(comparator);
  return resultList;
}
public static <T, G> List<G> toListOfNewType(List<T> inputList,
                                             Function<T, G> mapperFunction) {
  return inputList==null? Collections.emptyList():
    inputList.stream().map(mapperFunction).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

I would even consider dropping the support for a `null` input list, as it only leads to hiding problems instead of solving them.

An alternative would be:

```
public static <T, G> List<G> toListOfNewType(List<T> inputList,
                                             Function<T, G> mapperFunction,
                                             Comparator<? super G> comparator) {
  return toListOfNewTypeImpl(inputList, mapperFunction, s -> s.sorted(comparator));
}
public static <T, G> List<G> toListOfNewType(List<T> inputList,
                                             Function<T, G> mapperFunction) {
  return toListOfNewTypeImpl(inputList, mapperFunction, UnaryOperator.identity());
}
private static <T, G> List<G> toListOfNewTypeImpl(List<T> inputList,
                                                  Function<T, G> mapperFunction,
                                                  UnaryOperator<Stream<G>> lastOp) {
  return lastOp.apply(inputList.stream().map(mapperFunction)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: *I consider assigning a special meaning to `null` instead of clear overloaded methods a step into the wrong direction* +1. and of course great use of `UnaryOperator` in the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I might just have tested it with a very small input (and of course less efficient for performing element comparisons even when not required), but possibly this could do it :

```
public static <T, G> List<G> toListOfNewType(List<T> inputList, Function<T, G> mapperFunction) {
    return toListOfNewType(inputList, mapperFunction, (a, b) -> 0);
}
```

Comment: For further confirmation, have asked [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58782898/identity-operation-equivalent-for-comparator?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: That's possible, but bears some unnecessary overhead, as the implementation doesn't understand that the sorting operation is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a interesting thing to ask in my team over some code review too... The problem here is that if you allow a `nullable` `Comparator` you are defeating the purpose a bit. An `argument` that is a `Comparator` *and* is `null` is perfectly valid meaning of a *natural order* sort, meaning this is perfectly valid:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(2);
list.add(1);

Collections.sort(list, null);
```

Even if your *internal* implementation would not allow it as it is, meaning this:

```
List.of(4, 3, 2)
     .stream()
     .sorted(null)
     .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

would throw a `NullPointerException`.

So *unless* you clearly document what your intention is supposed to be for this method, users might be confused (I would).

IMHO it's not a lot of code to "duplicate" and you could enforce that users pass a `Function` that returns "something" that is `Comparable` by doing:

```
public static <T, G extends Comparable<? extends G>> List<G> sortedToListOfNewType(
    List<T> inputList,
    Function<T, G> mapperFunction) {

    return Stream.ofNullable(inputList)
                 .flatMap(List::stream)
                 .map(mapperFunction)
                 .sorted()
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static <T, G> List<G> toListOfNewType(
    List<T> inputList,
    Function<T, G> mapperFunction) {

    return Stream.ofNullable(inputList)
                 .flatMap(List::stream)
                 .map(mapperFunction)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The downside is that 1) duplicate code - that you try to avoid at all means it seems 2) these can not be overloaded methods - since the erasure is the same and the compiler would not allow this.

But, as said, this approach is very subjective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had the same feeling about allowing null as a comparator. So, I will probably leave both methods since confusing callers by allowing null while the sorted method in Stream class does not, might be a bad idea. But additionally, I decided to add a filter to eliminate nulls in the input list.

Comment: @KyleBak of course, if you _could_ not allow null lists to begin with, would be rather good too; but I understand it's not always possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to do that or I don't know. But if you would like to try my library: [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common), here is what you can do:

```
StreamEx.of(inputList)
    .map(mapperFunction)
    .__(s -> comparator == null ? s : s.sort(comparator))
    .toList()
```