# Identity operation equivalent for Comparator

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream, comparator

Is there a possible identity representation of `Comparator` that could exist?

In the search for simplifying the code in [Removing overloaded method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58782150/removing-overloaded-method-in-java/58782788#58782788), I thought about this and ended up concluding that if every comparison results in objects being equal, the order wouldn't really change making the operation an *identity*. Hence I ended up with (an inefficient) suggestion such as this:

```
public static <T, G> List<G> toListOfNewType(List<T> inputList, Function<T, G> mapperFunction) {
    return toListOfNewType(inputList, mapperFunction, (a, b) -> 0); // overloaded with comparator for 'G' type
}
```

But what I now wonder is, would this even hold for objects with their custom `compareTo` implementations as well? Is it really safe to assume this given the `Stream` implementation?

**Edit**: Certain tests that I'd tried and which retained the order were as follows:

```
List<Integer> integers = List.of(1, 3, 45356, 47424, 34234, 4, 4, 234234, 234, 0, -23, -34);
System.out.println(integers);
System.out.println(integers.stream().sorted((a, b) -> 0).collect(Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println(integers.stream().sorted((a, b) -> 0).parallel().collect(Collectors.toList()));

[1, 3, 45356, 47424, 34234, 4, 4, 234234, 234, 0, -23, -34]
[1, 3, 45356, 47424, 34234, 4, 4, 234234, 234, 0, -23, -34]
[1, 3, 45356, 47424, 34234, 4, 4, 234234, 234, 0, -23, -34]

List<String> strings = List.of("aadad", "Z", "vsadasd", "zadad", "C", "Aadasd");
System.out.println(strings);
System.out.println(strings.stream().sorted((a, b) -> 0).collect(Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println(strings.stream().sorted((a, b) -> 0).parallel().collect(Collectors.toList()));

[aadad, Z, vsadasd, zadad, C, Aadasd]
[aadad, Z, vsadasd, zadad, C, Aadasd]
[aadad, Z, vsadasd, zadad, C, Aadasd]

Set<Integer> integerSet = Set.of(1, 3, 45356, 47424, 34234, 4, 234234, 234, 0, -23, -34);
System.out.println(integerSet);
System.out.println(integerSet.stream().sorted((a, b) -> 0).parallel().collect(Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println(integerSet.stream().sorted((a, b) -> 0).collect(Collectors.toList()));

[-34, 45356, 47424, 234, -23, 234234, 1, 34234, 3, 4, 0]
[-34, 45356, 47424, 234, -23, 234234, 1, 34234, 3, 4, 0]
[-34, 45356, 47424, 234, -23, 234234, 1, 34234, 3, 4, 0]

Set<String> stringSet = Set.of("aadad", "Z", "vsadasd", "zadad", "C", "Aadasd");
System.out.println(stringSet);
System.out.println(stringSet.stream().sorted((a, b) -> 0).collect(Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println(stringSet.stream().sorted((a, b) -> 0).parallel().collect(Collectors.toList()));

[zadad, Z, vsadasd, C, Aadasd, aadad]
[zadad, Z, vsadasd, C, Aadasd, aadad]
[zadad, Z, vsadasd, C, Aadasd, aadad]
```

Comment: Or if I were to guess, it might just be safe for *ordered* characteristics?

Comment: I vaguely understand what is your question here; there are `stable` and `un-stable` sorting algorithms - it matters how _equal_ elements end up.

Comment: @Eugene the question is primarily around `(a,b) -> 0` used as a `Comparator` in `Stream.sorted` and producing no effect in the order of collection operating upon.

Comment: I'm not sure what the concern is. `(a, b) -> 0` means "all objects are equal", which implies having no effect for a stable sort operation. Whereas "custom `compareTo` implementations" are irrelevant, as the natural order always is irrelevant when you specify a `Comparator`. By the way, the behavior is similar to [`Comparator.nullsFirst(null)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst(java.util.Comparator)) when comparing non-`null` elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadoc of [`sorted(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) says:

> For *ordered* streams, the sort is **stable**.
>
> For *unordered* streams, **no stability guarantees** are made.

Of course, for an *unordered* stream, "identity" ordering isn't really a thing anyway, so yeah, the "constant comparator" is an "identity order", in that *ordered* streams retain their order, and *unordered* streams remain unordered.

Comment: The placement of the quoting marks irritated me a bit. I'd say, *for an unordered stream, "identity ordering" isn't really a thing anyway*, because "ordering" isn't really a thing anyway, i.e. it's not the "identity" that deserves emphasis.